# Having the tan(x), how can I get a tan(x/2)? In C

Tags: c, math

I know I can do this:

```
//With A = tax(x);
return tan(arctan(A)/2);
```

but I wanted something more efficient.

Comment: My math is bad but are you sure there is another way achieving in pure math? (not code, just math). If no then I do not think you can got a faster way with code. If you don't know, then you may want to ask in http://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Is this a measured bottleneck in your code? Have you actually measured or profiled your code to see that this is a problem?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg, nope. But I really wanted to avoid

Comment: This is more of a question about maths than about programming.

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg `tan()` with  `atan()` is a certainly slower than [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37934533/2410359).  Trig functions are often a sink-hole of time. They are in general, even if not for OP.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When `x` is between -π/2 and π/2 you can use this formula:

```
t / (1 + sqrt(1 + t*t))
```

This is hardly an improvement on the original formula, but it uses one function call instead of two.

**Note:** I found this formula [here](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A4%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D1%83%D0%BB%D0%B0_%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%B0_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0). The wikipedia page is in Russian, and the equivalent English page does not include the same formula.

Comment: Possibly `t/(1.0 + hypot(1.0, t));` may be more accurate - maybe more efficient. YMMV.